# How to dynamically create GWT UIBinder Element?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have a Widget with one Button and a DIV that should content dynamically generated Buttons in a `<g:HTMLPanel></g:HTMLPanel>`.

How can i proceed so that by clicking on this Button GWT Buttons are created and added into that DIV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative to the answer already given:

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="buttonPanel"></g:HTMLPanel>
```

Then, in your code, declare the panel as follows:

```
@UiField HTMLPanel buttonPanel;
```

And add your button like this:

```
buttonPanel.add(myButton);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give id to the div in the binder like

```
<div id='dynamicDiv'></div>
```

And in your code add elements as below

```
RootPanel.get("dynamicDiv").add(myButton1);

RootPanel.get("dynamicDiv").add(myButton2);
```

Make sure that the `dynamicDiv` is already added to the `DOM` before  you adding your buttons .